# How can i show previous day data till 11:59 PM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

How can i show previous day data till 11:59 PM or 12 ,

I am running a query using **`getdate()`** then it shows current date current time 
For example

```
Execution Datetime -2018-10-11 15:08:42.777
```

but if i want data of yesterday till 11:59 PM or 12 i used 
 **`dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), or Getdate()-1`**, it shows exactly of same time

```
2018-10-10 15:08:42.777
```

How can i get previous day data till `11:59 pm`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

```
where col < cast(getdate() as date) and
      col >= dateadd(day, -1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

This formulation allows SQL Server to use an index on `col`, if an appropriate one is available.

If you don't care about indexes, you can do:

```
where datediff(day, col, getdate) = 1
```

Comment: `cast(col as date) = somedate` also allows the server to use an index, because the condition is converted to a range query

Answer (score 0):

You can cast both the value *and* the field to `date`, eg :

```
where cast(dateTimeField as date) =cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) as date)
```

SQL Server is smart enough to convert this to a range query :

```
WHERE dateField >= '2018-10-10 00:00:00' and datefield <'2018-10-11 00:00:00`
```

This allows the server to use any indexes that cover `dateField` and perform a fast query.

In any other case, applying a function to a field would prevent the server from using indexes

**UPDATE**

For doubters and unepxlained downvoters, let's create a table with 50K entries :

```
create table TestDates(
    id int primary key identity,
    Name nvarchar(20),
    Created datetime,
    INDEX IX_TestDates_Created(Created)
    );


insert into TestDates(Name,Created)
select FORMAT(n,'John Doe {0}'), dateadd(hour,n,'2017-08-01  16:55:47') 
from Numbers
where n<=50000
```

This creates 50K entries up to 2023, with 24 entries per day.

The execution plan for this query :

```
select count(*),min(created),max(created)
from TestDates
where cast(created as date)=cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate()) as date)
```

Shows an index seek on the index instead of a scan.

[image]

The seek predicate for the Index Seek operation is :

```
Start: [Test].[dbo].[TestDates].Created > Scalar Operator([Expr1012]), 
End:   [Test].[dbo].[TestDates].Created < Scalar Operator([Expr1013])
```

With results :

```
24  2018-10-11 00:55:47.000 2018-10-11 23:55:47.000
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? It's only identical to the other answers after all ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below.

```
WHERE dateField < convert(date, getdate() -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` to get two values, one at 00:00:00 and one at 23:59:59 of yesterday. No conversions into DATE, very fast.

`DATEADD(DAY,-1, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,getdate()))` gives you yesterday 00:00:00
`DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,getdate())))` gives you yesterday 23:59:59.997

An example of this in the `WHERE` of a query to filter to yesterday,

```
SELECT *
FROM Sometable
WHERE Sometable.Datecolumn BETWEEN 
 DATEADD(DAY,-1, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,getdate()))  AND DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-3,DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,getdate())))
```

Comment: This doesn't affect performance at all. Casting to date is cleaner

Comment: On the other hand assuming there won't be any records after 23:59:59 guarantees that some rows will be lost. That's why `BETWEEN` can't be used in such queries. It will have to be a query like the one posted by Gordon, with `<` for the right boundary

Comment: Very true. I have edited my answer. Using a datediff and dateadd improves backwards compatibility before 2008 where the `DATE` datatype was introduced.